# Redirecting user to profile after sign up

Tags: python, django

I am overriding the sign up view in `allauth` by using my own. I can sign up and the user will be logged in, but I'd like to redirect the user to their profile page. I have an app called `profiles` that has a view called `Index` in the `profiles.urls` Index can take in 2 parameters, a slug (username) or a pk (id). After the user hits the sign up button and everything is valid, I want to redirect them to their profile page: `/profiles/{their username}`

**profiles.urls**

```
app_name = 'profiles'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Index.as_view(), name='Index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_]+)/$', views.Index.as_view(), name='Index'),
]
```

**oauth.views**

```
class RegisterView(SignupView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'oauth/auth_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect('profiles:Index', slug=form.username)
```

oauth.views is where I make my custom SignupView. Now when I try to sign up, I don't get redirected to the user's profile. Instead I get this error:

```
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 102, in post
    response = self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\examplesite\oauth\views.py", line 17, in form_valid
    return redirect('profiles:Index', slug=form.username)
AttributeError: 'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'username'
```

How do I make it so that the user is redirected to their profile based on the username they selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class RegisterView(SignupView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'oauth/auth_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect('profiles:Index', slug=form.cleaned_data['username'])
```

Comment: Which package should I import for cleaned_data? It's not recognizing it

Comment: sorry made a mistake, try now

Comment: Thanks! It does work, but could you please explain to me why we use `cleaned_data`?

Comment: well because your form has many fields and inside form_valid function the fields can be accessed with the name and cleaned data

Comment: would it be possible to access the username field without the form_valid function. For example, in `success_url`?

Comment: Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: depends on what type of view you are using, if class based, then answered one and if function based then the one in the comment

Comment: What type of view i'm using for the redirected url or for the SignupView?

Comment: that one is class based view

Comment: I gotcha, so for my example it would be best to use it in form_valid